# Genetic Algorithm: Creating Offspring of Two HashMaps

Tags: java, hashmap, genetic-algorithm

I need to do create offspring from two arrays, if possible with HashMaps.

Here is my reproduce function:

```
public Map<String, Integer> reproduce(Map<String, Integer> x, Map<String, Integer> y, int n){
Random rand = new Random();
int c = rand.nextInt(n);
!!CREATE OFFSPRING from x and y and store it into child!!
return(child);
}
```

For example if the x and y values passed to the function are:

```
x = {0=1} {1=0} {2=1}
```

and

```
y = {0=2} {1=1} {2=2}
```

I would like to reproduce using these Maps to create a child map like for example:

```
child = {0=1} {1=1} {2=2}
```

The child has taken the first tuple from x, and the 2nd and 3rd tuples from y.

The point where it switches from x to y is determined by the random number c.

How can I do this without converting the maps to arrays?

Comment: show us your code. we need to see what you tried.

Comment: I don't know how to do it at all. I am looking for a way to do it i.e trying to get a suggestion for what to put on the !!Create offspring!! line

Comment: What I think i need to do is something like this:
~~~ for(int i = 0; i < c; i++){//store value from x(i) in child at location i} THEN for(int i = c; i<n; i++){//store value from x(i) in child at location i}~~~
BUT I dont know how do do this

Comment: well, I'm sorry. but stackoverflow is not here to solve your homework. you need to make some effort and when you have specific problems you can ask us. genetic algorythms are pretty straight forward. just adapt them to your problem.

Comment: please don't add code in the comments. edit your question

Comment: I'm sorry I am new to stack overflow. I didn't know I should have edited the question there. However I have done about 300 lines of code on this problem without help and I just needed to ask how to do this specific section I don't see what the problem with asking is? Also this is the first time I have ever seen/learnt about a Genetic Algorithm so I just wanted some help

Comment: well then show us the code and tell us what problem(s) it's having.

Comment: this looks like homework. I'm in doubt your professor didn't teach you about it.

Comment: I have a method from lectures to like this:
APPEND(Substring(x, 1, c), Substring(y, c+1, n). 
But that isn't for a HashMap which is what I am using

Comment: I'll read this question in a few hours. Show some effort....

Comment: Do `x` and `y` always have the same keys? Is it a requirement that you take the first bindings from `x` and the last bindings from `y`, or can you mix them in any way the program can come up with?

Comment: To take the first `c` tuples from `x`, if `x` has keys 1, 3, 9, 10, 20, which are the first? 1, 3, 9 as in numeric order? If so, are all keys numeric? Or better 1, 10, 20 as in the natural order of the strings?

Comment: x has keys 0, 1, 2 ... n and matching values rand(n), rand(n), rand(n), rand(n) and y is the same. I want to take the first c tupes from x and combine them with the c+1 to n tuples from y and return the result

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, the `Map` interface in java does not have a method for sequential access.
So you can't take "x first elements" from a map - there's no order between them.
Some implementations do have guaranteed ordering - SortedMap (sorted by keys) and LinkedHashMap (sorted by order of insertion).

In these cases, you can use the `entryMap()` method.

So (assuming n is the size of both maps) if you want to take x element from the first and y elements from the second you could create two iterators and take from them, something like:

```
int c = rand.nextInt(n);
Iterator<Entry<String, Integer>> i1 = x.entrySet().iterator();
Iterator<Entry<String, Integer>> i2 = y.entrySet().iterator();
int i = 0;
Map<Integer, String> child = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
Entry<String, Integer> e1, e2;
while (i < n)
{ 
   if (i < c) {
     e1= i1.next();
     e2 = i2.next();
     child.add(e1.getKey(), e1.getValue());
   }
   else
   {
     e2 = i2.next();
     child.add(e2.getKey(), e2.getValue());
   }
   i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am taking your word for it: You want the first `c` tuples from `x` and the remainder from `y`. In the natural order of the keys as defined by `String.compareTo()`. This is a bit more complicated than just taking each tuple from `x` or `y` at random. Of course it can be done.

As @Yossi Vainshtein already pointed out in another answer, a map generally doesn’t maintain an order of tuples, so it would not make sense to ask the map for the first `c` tuples. So we need to sort the keys explicitly. Before we can sort them, we need to have them in a different data strucure, a list or an array. So I take out the keys into a list and sort it. So while it is without converting the maps themselves to arrays, I do convert the key set only to a list which behind the scenes is implemented through an array.

This way of doing it only works as expected if the two parent maps have the same keys. So the first thing your method should do is check whether this is the case.

For taking the keys out of a map, use `x.keySet()`, similarly for `y`. To put them into a list, use `new ArrayList<>(x.keySet())`. To sort the list, use `Collections.sort()`. To create the empty child, use `Map<String, Integer> child = new HashMap<>();`. To fill it, iterate over the first `c` elements of the list and fill in the corresponding key and value from `x`; then iterate over the remaining keys and fill in key and value from `y`. Then you’re done.

If you didn’t care which `c` tuples were taking fomr `x` as long as you take `c` from `x` and `n - c` from `y`, we could skip the list and the sorting completely.

EDIT: I understand from your comment that the keys are always 0 through `n - 1`. In this case there is no reason to take the keys out of the maps and sort them. Just iterate over the numbers 0 through `c - 1`. For each number, convert it to a string, take the value from `x` and put the string and the value into the child. Then do the same with numbers `c` through `n - 1` and `y`. Quite a bit simpler than what I outlined above.

**Link:** [Answer by Yossi Vainshtein](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43179095/genetic-algorithm-creating-offspring-of-two-hashmaps/43179677#43179677)

Comment: Thankyou I implemented this solution. 
I have updated the question with what I used.